# How to achieve this image distortion effect in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, image, image-processing

I'm building an iphone photo app. I don't know how to achieve this kind of effect on an image:

[image]

When the user drags a finger across the arrow, I want the image to be distorted accordingly. How can I achieve this? Is there any framework that makes this process simple?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clue about iOS, but the look reminds me of a [thin-plate spline warp](https://www.google.com/search?q=thin%20plate%20spline%20image%20warping&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=929&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=R6NSVN3DEMeAygTkwYGgBQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#tbm=isch&q=thin%20plate%20spline%20image%20warp). It's quite easy to implement in OpenGL, a quick Google search for example code returns plenty of hits.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. I'll look into it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the effect with grid warping using OpenGL ES. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @Jinx Can you pls share code or do you have it on Github?

Answer (score -1):

From the sound of it I think your looking for the [CoreImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) framework. Look into the various distortion effects...in particular [CIBumpDistortionLinear](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBumpDistortionLinear).

I don't have any code so check out this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22167/beginning-core-image-in-ios-6) and read up on CoreImage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Roecrew. Actually, I did look at CIBumpDistortionLinear before asking the question. The problem is the effect it makes, which is a kind of a "bump strip" as you can see here [link](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.CoreImage.CIBumpDistortionLinear), is not what I want. Another problem is I couldn't make it work (even with default arguments) although the CIBumpDistortion worked fine.